# Saved Search of Saved Searches with Email Subject and Body in results tab

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

I'm trying to create saved search of saved searches in order to see which saved search is sending which e-mail. Now once i have like 100 auto e-mails from saved searches in netsuite i would like to organize them.

For example i would like to have all active saved search with results :

1. Search name
2. Search ID
3. Email Subject
4. Email Body
5. Receipts

All i could find for now is 1(Name),2(Internal ID) and 5 (SearchSchedule : Recipient).

And just to mention this saved searches that i'm looking for are scheduled with an daily or weekly event which will trigger e-mail to go out.

Is there a way of getting 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a search of type Analytics Audit Trail with the following criteria:

- Record Type is Search AND
- (Detail Name is Subject OR Detail Name is Body) AND
- Saved Search : Scheduled is true

and the results:

- Record Title
- Component Name
- Detail Name
- New Value

This gives you the history of the Subject and Body (values of Detail Name) for each search (value of record title). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use Netsuite Email Plugin

```
function process(email) {
        // log all information in email
        var fromAddress = email.getFrom();
        var recipientemail = email.getTo();
          log('replyTo', email.getReplyTo());
            log('sent', email.getSentDate());
            log('subject', email.getSubject());
            log('text body', email.getTextBody());
            log('html body', email.getHtmlBody());
}
```

Forward or keep the cc of the email to a netsuite account mail id

Comment: How does this help to find which search sends an email with a specific subject and body?